# React prop not transferring in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, redux

Having a weird problem with React props in Firefox. Using Redux and Babel as well.

I'm trying to hide a form, once it has submitted. This works fine on Chrome, but for some reason doesn't work on FF and IE.

So here I have a simple component, a div which houses a form. `display` class comes from parent component:

```
class MyForm extends Component {

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    // fires an action that sets submitInfo to true
  }

  render() {
    const { display } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={display}>
        <form onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleFormSubmit(e) }>
          // some inputs here
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When the form submits, an action is fired that sets `submitInfo` (Redux state) is set to true.

The parent component looks like this:

```
import { submitInfo, hideForm } from '../actions/main.js'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {submitInfo, hideForm} = this.props;

    var showForm;
    if ((submitInfo == true) || (hideForm == true)) {
      console.log('evaluating showForm');
      showForm = 'hide';
    } else {
      console.log('evaluating showForm');
      showForm = '';
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <MyForm display={ 'main-form' + ' ' + showForm } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { submitInfo, hideForm } = state;
    return { submitInfo, hideForm }
}
```

The parent component checks Redux state for `submitInfo = true` or `hideForm = true`. If true then pass value of 'hide' to child component.

Can seem to figure out what is wrong. In Chrome, my `console.logs` within the parent component seem to be firing every time the state object is re-rendered (ie. whenever an action is fired), but this doesn't happen in Firefox.

State object is being updated correctly, so I can see `submitInfo: true` and `hideForm: true` when they're supposed appropriate.

Comment: Should class name be `main-formhide`, because it looks like that's what you will get from that code.

Comment: oops - I've corrected it... I'm concatenating a space before `main-form`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a conditional instead of a class to determine whether to show a component.

The parent component's render method would look something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!(this.props.submitInfo && this.props.hideForm) ? <MyForm /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now we can also clean up the child component:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    // fires an action that sets submitInfo to true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-form">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}>
          ...
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```